# CERTCC / keyfinder ''clean up mismatched '/' and '\\' directory separators problem''

Tags: python

i tried using this keyfinder https://github.com/CERTCC/keyfinder/blob/master/keyfinder.py
but py file everytime crashing and it gives this error:

```
 keyfinder\keyfinder.py:1228: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
 appname = re.sub('\.apk$', '', apkfile)
```

and in the application it says: 'clean up mismatched '/' and '' directory separators''